# Variable getting undefined inside whereExist function - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel but having problem fetching records with dynamic date.

```
$date = '2015-03-04';
    $records_all = DB::table('clients')
       ->whereExists(function($query)
       {
         $query->select(DB::raw(1))
         ->from('fb_page')
         ->whereRaw('fb_page.client_id = clients.client_id')
         ->whereNotExists(function($query)
         {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('fb_stats')
            ->whereRaw('fb_stats.fb_page_id = fb_page.fb_page_id')
            ->where('fb_stats.recorded_on','=',$date); //$date here is undefined
         });
   })
   ->get();
```

when using whereExist for some reason, $date is getting undefined.

Comment: Variable scope rules still apply inside closures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually pass the variable to the closure with the `use` construct:

```
->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($date)
{
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
          ->from('fb_stats')
          ->whereRaw('fb_stats.fb_page_id = fb_page.fb_page_id')
          ->where('fb_stats.recorded_on','=',$date);
});
```

From the [PHP Docs on Anonymous Functions](https://php.net/manual/ro/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.